# Parsing Error during Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, xml

Im new here! I want to ask some help about my code, I used XML to set my query.
`<add key="atstr" value="{vquery: EXECUTE spSomething @str1 = 'A', @str2 = 'B'}" />`

Now on my c# code:

```
if(region.Length > 0)
{
     foreach(var item in strX.Split(','))
     exQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["atstr"];
     dynamic dynaATSTR = JObject.Parse(exQuery);
     Console.WriteLine(dynaATSTR.vquery);
     break;
}
```

I got this error message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered.

I believed it has something to do with the "'" (Apostrophe). Because I believed it breaks the string inside the XML file while Json read the string as different and breaks every string.

Can someone help me with it?  I looked and tried some codes from this community but nothing works.

Comment: It's not valid JSON on a number of fronts. The property value isn't quoted. The string value isn't quoted at all.

Comment: Yep that is what I am thinking for. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't force tags into question titles. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags

Answer (score 0):

Your code is effectively doing this:

```
if(region.Length > 0)
{
     foreach(var item in strX.Split(','))
     {
         exQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["atstr"];
     }
     dynamic dynaATSTR = JObject.Parse(exQuery);
     Console.WriteLine(dynaATSTR.vquery);
     break;
}
```

Im pretty sure thats not what you intended..

also try:

```
<add key="atstr" value="{vquery: \"EXECUTE spSomething @str1 = 'A', @str2 = 'B'\"}" />
```

Comment: Hi @meganaut
I think we have some misunderstanding on the `Split`, the code was nothing do it with the `Split` because I had an array assigned to that, what I am trying to achieved with my question is that I want to get the whole query inside the vquery and parse it for every value assigned from that key.  Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add key="atstr" value="{ &quot;vquery&quot;: &quot;EXECUTE spSomething @str1 = 'A', @str2 = 'B'&quot;}" />
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256152(v=vs.110).aspx